# How do I find a row that matches all fields

Tags: c#, sql

I have a model

```
public void CarModel()
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Brand {get; set;}
    public string Color {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a database table called `Vehicles`

```
id | Name    | Brand    | Color  | ...
---+---------+----------+--------+--------
1  | carA    | A        | Green  |
2  | carB    | C        | Red    |
3  | carC    | D        | Orange |
4  | carA    | C        | White  |
```

And then I wanted to find this one specifically

```
---+---------+----------+--------+--------
3  | carC    | D        | Orange |
```

Without knowing the ID just by knowing the Name, Brand & Color.

I want to fetch all the entries if that's the correct term using SQL syntax.

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different products with slightly different sql syntax. I removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use.

Comment: In SQL or in C#?? you can try with linq

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution with [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8) syntax:

```
var vehicles = _db.Vehicles.Where(r=>r.Name=="carC" && r.Brand="D" && r.Color=="Orange").ToList();
```

Comment: Yes. You are right @RistoM as `Name, Brand and color` fields are not containing list.. We use `SelectMany() ` against collection to get flat list of particular property.
I deleted my answer and +1 for you...

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select * from Vehicles
where name='carC' and brand='D' and color='Orange'
```